# Avoid too much conversion

Tags: go

I have some parts in my current Go code that look like this:

```
i := int(math.Floor(float64(len(l)/4)))
```

The verbosity seems necessary because of some function type signatures like the one in `math.Floor`, but can it be simplified?

Comment: we need a better (actually worse) code example;) here is a naive binomial distribution calculation _written by a newbie (me)_: **`float64(z.Binomial(int64(N), int64(k)).Int64()) * math.Pow(probability, float64(k)) * math.Pow(1-probability, float64(N-int32(k)))`** where `N, k int32; probability float64; z := new(big.Int)` , and `z` comes from "math/bin". Most versions I saw (JS, Python, Perl, even C++) looked better. PS: originally `probability` was float32... so - much more conversions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, the strict typing of Go leads to some verbose expressions.  Verbose doesn't mean stuttering though.  Type conversions do useful things and it's valuable to have those useful things explicitly stated.

The trick to simplification is to not write unneeded type conversions, and for that you need to refer to documentation such as the language definition.

In your specific case, you need to know that len() returns int, and further, a value >= 0.  You need to know that 4 is a constant that will take on the type int in this expression, and you need to know that integer division will return the integer quotient, which in this case will be a non-negative int and in fact exactly the answer you want.

```
i := len(l)/4
```

This case is an easy one.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your reply. This is an easy example, but it gets annoying with expressions like `math.Max`, for example.

Comment: "You need to know that 4 is a constant that will take on the type int in this expression".  I'm curious, how do you know that, because constants don't have a particular type?

Comment: a little bit more difficult example and the same question: `float64(z.Binomial(int64(N), int64(k)).Int64()) * math.Pow(probability, float64(k)) * math.Pow(1-probability, float64(N-int32(k)))` (it is a binomial distribution without a statistics lib). i have `N, k int32`, and `probability float64`, and `z := new(big.Int)` (from "math/bin"). and even in C++ it looks MUCH better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure how Go deals with integer division and integer conversion, but it's usually via truncation.  Thus, assuming len(l) is an int

```
i:=len(l)/4
```

Otherwise `i:= int(len(l))/4` or `i:=int(len(l)/4)` should work, with the first being theoretically slightly faster than the second.